# ADF Copy with Polybase from Parquet to SQL DW Failing with error: recordReaderFillBuffer

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In a production setup, using ADF,
We are invoking an API, storing the data into Parquet on raw zone.
and then load data to staging layer on SQL DW.

We have encountered sometimes the Copy Data Activity fails with error:

> ErrorCode=PolybaseOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error happened when loading data into SQL Data Warehouse. Operation: 'Polybase operation'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException: ,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=106000,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=106000,State=1,Message=HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException: ,},],'

There is no mapping defined in the Copy Data Activity.

datetime fields in parquet is coming as INT96 datatype, which is stored into a datetime field on target table on SQL DW

Answer (score 0):

> [{Class=16,Number=106000,State=1,Message=HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException: ,},],'

***Ther error you are facing is a datatype mismatch between parquet file and SQL DW columns.***

**To resolve this:**

- Check if your file has column with proper Timestamp format and then try to copy into SQL DW.
- You can use dataflows in ADF to change the datatype of particular column use Cast transformation in the data flows.
  [image]

Reference: [Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: ClassCastException](https://medium.com/@Lijitha/unexpected-error-encountered-filling-record-reader-buffer-classcastexception-9d908a9faf00)